# Automapper setting inner object property

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I set an inner property of a nested object using Automapper?
Shareholder has inner property of class Contacts.
Property PhysicalOrPostalAddresses needs to be mapped to Individual.Address or Corporate.Addresses.

```
var holderMap = CreateMap<Shareholder, Trustee>(MemberList.None);
        holderMap
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Individual, opt =>
        {
            opt.Condition(src => src.Person != null);
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Person);
        })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Corporate, opt =>
        {
            opt.Condition(src => src.Organisation != null);
            opt.MapFrom(src => src.Organisation);
        })
        // this code doesn't work
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Corporate.Addresses, o =>
        {
            o.Condition(s => s.Organisation != null);
            o.MapFrom(s => s.Contacts.PhysicalOrPostalAddresses);
        })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Individual.Addresses, o =>
        {
            o.Condition(s => s.Person != null);
            o.MapFrom(s => s.Contacts.PhysicalOrPostalAddresses);
        })
    .ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ForPath instead of ForMember.

Comment: thank you! It works. How to specify condition like for ForMember `opt.Condition(src => src.Organisation != null);`

Comment: That's not supported right now. You can request it on github.